# How to count time in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, triggers, counter

I am creating a game that when an object is tracked it changes color and becomes red, how to count the time between the start of the game and the color change?
Maybe export it in a txt file would be perfect.

I was thinking something like this:
A timer script

```
public float timer = 0.0f;

void Start()
{
    timer = 0;
}

void Update()
{

    timer += Time.Time;
    print(second);
}
```

Than a trigger on the eyetracking:

```
void CountStop()
{
    // i don't know how to stop the count and save the value
}
```

Comment: If you want the absolute time since the application start just use `Time.time`? And I don't see the connection between getting the time and coloring "tracked" objects?

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: This doesn't work and you need to improve your programming skills before making your project. but if you insist to just solve this, the easier way is use InvokeRepeating. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html

Comment: @willow Maybe i was not clear, i did everything just don't know how to stop the timer counter and save its value in a variable, that's not a programming skills just a unity/c# better understanding

Comment: You don't need to keep track of the time yourself. Once you need to get it, it's as easy `Time.time`. That will be the time between the start of the game and the time your event is triggered. If you mean that you want to get the difference between tracking started and tracking ended, then save the value of `Time.time` in a variable when tracking begins, then when tracking ends subtract that save value from the new `Time.time` to get the difference.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, Unity itself has taken the trouble of this, just use `Time.time`:

```cs
private void OnGUI() => GUILayout.Box($"Current Time: {Time.time}");
```

But you said that you want to change the color of an object. In this regard, you can use `Color.Lerp`, but depending on the **shader** and **material** you use on your object, flexibility may be required. In the code below, enter the `meshRenderer` value in the inspector and the changes will be made. I hope this guide solves your problem.

```cs
[SerializeField] private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;

[SerializeField] private float lerpTime = 4f; // 4 seconds
[SerializeField] private Color color;
private void Update()
{
    meshRenderer.material.color = Color.Lerp(meshRenderer.material.color, color, Time.time / lerpTime);
}
```

---

### Making a Simple Tweener

If you want to have a temporary timer like below, make a tweener with several callbacks, which is a relatively more advanced technique.

```cs
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(TweenTimer(2f, f =>
        {
            Debug.Log($"Tween Time: {f}");
        },
        () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Timer End.");
        }));
}
private IEnumerator TweenTimer(float duration, Action<float> onTime = null, Action onEnd = null)
{
    var _timer = 0f;
    while (_timer <= duration)
    {
        _timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime);
        onTime?.Invoke(_timer);
    }
    onEnd?.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: I already did the changing of the object color when it is tracked, i just need a timer that counts the time between the start of the game and when the object change color, save this time in a variable and thats it

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, to get the time since the start of your application, simply use `Time.time` like this for example:

```
// Assuming this is called by you e.g. if the color changes
void CountStop()
{
    float timeSinceStart = Time.time;
}
```

If you don't need the time since the start of the application but rather starting at a certain point in time you can measure time manually by accumulating time over frames with `Time.deltaTime` or `Time.unscaledDeltaTime`. Unscaled means it is not influenced by application `timescale` (real time). For example you could do the following:

```
float elapsedTime = 0f;
bool measuretime = false;

// Call to start measuring time in Update() method
void StartTimer()
{
    measureTime = true;
{

// Call to stop measuring time in Update() method
void StopTimer()
{
    measureTime = false;
}

// Call to reset timer
void ResetTimer()
{
    elapsedTime = 0f;
}

// Call to get measured time
float GetMeasuredTime()
{
    return elapsedTime;
}

// Unity built-in Update() method
void Update()
{
    if (measureTime)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
    }
}
```